# Any propositional formula can be proved equivalent to a canonical form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

The followings are taken form *Mathematics for Computer Science* by Albert R. Meyer, Eric Lehman, and Frank T.Leighton.

> Theorem 1. Using the propositional equivalence axioms, any propositional formula can be proved equivalent to a canonical form.
>
> What has this got to do with equivalence? That’s easy: to prove that two formulas
> are equivalent, convert them both to canonical forms over the set of variables that
> appear in at least one of the formulas—call these the combined variables. Now
> if two formulas are equivalent to the same canonical form then the formula are
> certainly equivalent. Conversely, the way we read off a full disjunctive normal
> form from a truth table actually yields a canonical form. So if two formulas are
> equivalent, they will have the same truth table over the combined variables, and
> therefore they will have the same canonical form. This proves
>
> Theorem 2 (Completeness of the propositional equivalence axioms). Two propositional
> formula are equivalent iff they can be proved equivalent using the equivalence
> axioms listed above.

I know any propositional formula can be transformed both a full disjunctive normal form and a full conjunctive normal form from which we can easily derive a canonical form of a propositional formula. This part is OK. what I don't understand is explanation below Theorem 1: what is combined variables and their role? Above all, how do theorem 1 imply that the set of propositional equivalence axioms is complete? Appreciate your answers.

Comment: "combined" because they appear either in one formula or in the other.

Comment: The reasoning is: using equiv axioms we can produce canonical form of formula A and canonical form of formula B. If the two canonical forms are the same, the two formulas A and B are equivalent: transitivity of equivalence.